# How to detach the panel to a separate window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a dual monitor setup. I frequently have my VSCode open in monitor-1 displaying both my editor and panel (e.g. output, problems, debug console, and terminal).  To increase the area of my editor, I'd like to detach the panel and drag it to monitor-2.  Is this at all possible, even with hacks or third party solutions? The issue was posed to the VSCode team several years ago ([see here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121)), but it hasn't been implemented as a native feature yet.

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1319288/vs-code-drag-tab-to-new-window) is to a different question.  But for posterity, I tried the answers suggested there (including Duplicate Workspace in New Window and Open Active File in New Window). Those solutions do indeed allow me to open my file in two separate VSCode windows.  But the panel in window 2 will not auto-update if I edit/save the editor in window 1.  That is a requirement in my case.

As a last resort, I can indeed horizontally drag my VSCode window wider, so that it stretches into monitor-2. But I just thought I'd ask if there were any other solutions.

Comment: Actually dragging the window onto two screens is not a general option.

E.g. I have a setup with 3 external display, with 2 regular monitors (different resolutions), one vertical monitor (for technical reasons I cannot make them the same, one must use a VGA connector), and a laptop under the left wing of my wall mounted displays.